# HttpClient : "Resource temporarily unavailable" when sending requests asynchronously

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I've written a application to generate a load to a REST API endpoint. Sending the requests synchronously from my local machine I can amount to around 15 Rps. I had the idea to send the requests asynchronously and when it works, I get 2-3x more Rps than in the beginning.

The issue I have is that sending requests asynchronously usually (roughly 80% of the time) throws me an exception inside the HttpClient `Resource temporarily unavailable` and with inner exception of

```
{System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)}
```

Now, for my API client I have a single static HttpClient and a method SendRequestsAsync

```
        public async Task<RestResponse[]> SendRequestsAsync(string apiUrl, int count)
        {
            var tasks = new Task<RestResponse>[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = SendRequest(apiUrl);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToArray();
        }
```

My assumption is that I'm running out of sockets but I don't know where go from here. Is there a way to run as many requests as possible on a machine without encountering this exception or a request to wait for available sockets?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @LilacBlue If I remember correctly, I had kept a bunch of sockets open while prototyping. Restarting my machine fixed it and I have not seen the issue since.